# Bar Graph Effect: Aligning Multiple DIVs to Bottom when Side by Side

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of my problem:
http://www.rhexi.com/images/uploads/example.jpg

I am trying to align multiple side-by-side divs to the bottom within a parent div.  The end result I am trying to achieve is a **bar graph**, where you have a parent container, and multiple bar divs a the bottom within the parent.

I have successfully embedded the child bar divs within the container div, but they are all aligned top.  How do i get it to align bottom?

I do not want to use position: absolute and bottom: 0 since these bars need to be floating.

Here is my code:

```
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: 1px solid #000;">
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 10px; background: #00f; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 5px; background: #f00; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue using this technique, but need skybondsor's answer to be aligned with the bottom of the "screen" without using absolute positioning on each bar, just make use of your margin style. Your margin-top should be equal to:

margin-top = height_of_graph - height_of_bar

So, in the example set by skybondsor, this worked for me:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: 1px solid #000;position:relative;">
    <div style="width: 199px; height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
        <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left; margin-top: 30px;"></div>
        <div style="width: 20px; height: 10px; background: #00f; margin-left: 1px; float: left; margin-top: 40px;"></div>
        <div style="width: 20px; margin-top: 45px; height: 5px; background: #f00; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being the only solution that worked for me (suprisingly there was no valign=bottom type of solution).  The main trick needed to make this work was to ensure that the resulting top margin was rounded off, that threw me for a loop for a moment.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure. I had done graphs before using absolute positioning, but you challenged us all to find a more elegant solution. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating 3 divs instead of 1? Something like this:

```
<div style="width: 20px; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; float: left;">
    <div style="height: 80px;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100%; background: #000;"></div>
</div>
..
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what rfausak is also getting at, but position: absolute, bottom: 0 is the only way to do this.  Fortunately, nesting one level deeper will allow you to achieve the effect without losing your floats.

```
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: 1px solid #000;position:relative;">
        <div style="width: 199px; height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 10px; background: #00f; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
            <div style="width: 20px; height: 5px; background: #f00; margin-left: 1px; float: left;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just tried this bit of code and the bars within the bar graph are still aligned to the top instead of the bottom.

Comment: Hm, you know what. I think this is really only a partial solution.  But I've thought of a better one, which I'll post as a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make each bar a div nested inside another div and then make the background of the container div the color you want your bar to be, with the nested div the color of the background of the chart.  Then, rather than giving the nested div the height you desire, you can give it the inverse.

E.g. something like:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: 1px solid #fff;">
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 50px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left;">
     <div style="width: 20px; height: 30px; background: #fff;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 50px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left;">
     <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #fff;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 50px; background: #000; margin-left: 1px; float: left;">
     <div style="width: 20px; height: 10px; background: #fff;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hahha and now I see Atomox utterly beat me to this solution. Carry on, everyone!